# lock height of div element to the size of its child elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I have three divs inside `.main` div displayed as `flex`. I'm trying to do basic swipe to get to next/previous divs. I can't figure out how to dynamically specify `.main` divs height according to its current child element's`#wrapper` height.

```js
const main = document.querySelector('.main');
N = main.children.length;
let i = 0,
    x0 = null,
    locked = false,
    w;
function unify(e) {
    return e.changedTouches ? e.changedTouches[0] : e
};
function lock(e) {
    x0 = unify(e).clientX;
    main.classList.toggle('smooth', !(locked = true))
};
function drag(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (locked)
        main.style.setProperty('--tx', `${Math.round(unify(e).clientX - x0)}px`)
};
function move(e) {
    if (locked) {
        let dx = unify(e).clientX - x0,
            s = Math.sign(dx),
            f = +(s * dx / w).toFixed(2);
        if ((i > 0 || s < 0) && (i < N - 1 || s > 0) && f > .2) {
            main.style.setProperty('--i', i -= s);
            f = 1 - f
        }
        main.style.setProperty('--tx', '0px');
        main.style.setProperty('--f', f);
        main.classList.toggle('smooth', !(locked = false));
        x0 = null
    }
};
function size() {
    w = window.innerWidth
};
size();
main.style.setProperty('--n', N);
addEventListener('resize', size, false);
main.addEventListener('mousedown', lock, false);
main.addEventListener('touchstart', lock, false);
main.addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
main.addEventListener('touchmove', drag, false);
main.addEventListener('mouseup', move, false);
main.addEventListener('touchend', move, false);
```

```css
.main {
    --n: 1;
    display: flex;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    width: calc(var(--n)*100%);
    /* height: 50vw; max-height: 100vh; */
    transform: translate(calc(var(--tx, 0px) + var(--i, 0)/var(--n)*-100%));
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    width: calc(100%/var(--n));
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none
}

.smooth { transition: transform  calc(var(--f, 1)*.3s) ease-out }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div>
            <h1>Page 0</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
                culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div>
            <h1>Page 1 here!!!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div>
            <h1>page2 some stuff goes here!!!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. The `wrapper` ids (which should be classes, not ids) are children of `main` which is set to `display: flex`. As the default is [align-items: stretch](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#prop-align-items) for things with `display: flex`, all the `wrappers` height will stretch to be the same height.

Comment: So you are suggesting not using flex? And why wrapper must be class and not id?

Comment: Because an `id` is only to be used once in a HTML page.